# PYsimpleGUI: not possible to repeat an event using radio button

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I developed a pack app that can run 3 functions depending on the user's choice:

It is pretty simple:

[image]

For each option, we have another window to upload the required files an run the routine as follows:

[image]

However, if I choose option A, once I ran the script I can't run A again, I need to close and open the application again.

Please check this example (try to run the same option (A, B or C) without close the app):

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# --------------------------------------------- Menu Definition -------------------------------------------------------#
menu_def = [["Help", ["Applications description", "Template"]]]

# --------------------------------------------- GUI Definition ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
layout = [[sg.Menu(menu_def, tearoff = False, background_color="lightgray", disabled_text_color="white", text_color = "black")],
          [sg.Text("Choose the application:", s = 14, text_color = 'black', background_color='lightgray', size = (30,1))],[sg.Radio('A', default=False, key="-IN-", group_id = "Group 1", background_color="lightgray", size = (5,5), text_color= "black")],
          [sg.Radio('B', default=False, key="-IN2-", group_id = "Group 1", background_color="lightgray", size = (5,5), text_color= "black")], [sg.Radio('C', default=False, key="-IN3-", group_id = "Group 1", background_color="lightgray", size = (5,5), text_color= "black")],
          [sg.Button('Submit', button_color=("black"), mouseover_colors="white"), sg.Button('Exit', button_color=("tomato"))]]
window = sg.Window("Pack App", layout, background_color= 'lightgray')

layout_app1 = [[sg.Text("A1 File:", s = 14, text_color = 'black', background_color='white')], [sg.Input(key="-IN-", justification='left'), sg.FileBrowse(file_types = (("Text Files","*.txt"),), button_color = 'darkgray')],
              [sg.Text("A2 File:", s = 14, text_color = 'black', background_color='white', size = (40,1))], [sg.Input(key="-IN2-", justification='left'), sg.FileBrowse(file_types = (("Text Files","*.txt"),), button_color='darkgray')],
              [sg.Text("Output Folder:", s = 14, text_color = 'black', background_color='white')], [sg.Input(key="-OUT-"), sg.FolderBrowse(button_color=('darkgray'))],
              [sg.Text("File Name:", s = 14, text_color = 'black', background_color='white', size = (8,1)), sg.Input(key="-IN3-", background_color='white', justification='left', size = (34,1))],
              [[sg.T("", background_color='white')], sg.Button("Generate File", s = 16, button_color='darkblue')]]

window_app1 = sg.Window("First Application", layout_app1, background_color= 'white')

layout_app2 = [[sg.Text("B1:", s = 14, text_color = 'black', background_color='white')], [sg.Input(key="-IN-", justification='left'), sg.FileBrowse(file_types = (("Excel Files","*.xlsx"),), button_color = 'darkgray')],
               [sg.Text("Output Folder:", s = 14, text_color = 'black', background_color='white')], [sg.Input(key="-OUT-"), sg.FolderBrowse(button_color=('darkgray'))],
               [sg.Text("File Name:", s = 14, text_color = 'black', background_color='white', size = (8,1)), sg.Input(key="-IN3-", background_color='white', justification='left', size = (34,1))],
               [[sg.T("", background_color='white')], sg.Button("Generate File", s = 16, button_color='darkblue')]]

window_app2 = sg.Window("Second Application", layout_app2, background_color= 'white')

layout_app3 = [[sg.Text("C1:", s = 14, text_color = 'black', background_color='white', size = (35,1))], [sg.Input(key="-IN-", justification='left'), sg.FileBrowse(file_types = (("Excel Files","*.xlsx"),), button_color = 'darkgray')],
               [sg.Text("Output Folder:", s = 14, text_color = 'black', background_color='white')], [sg.Input(key="-OUT-"), sg.FolderBrowse(button_color=('darkgray'))],
               [sg.Text("File Name:", s = 14, text_color = 'black', background_color='white', size = (8,1)), sg.Input(key="-IN3-", background_color='white', justification='left', size = (34,1))],
               [[sg.T("", background_color='white')], sg.Button("Generate File", s = 16, button_color='darkblue')]]

window_app3 = sg.Window("Third Application", layout_app3, background_color= 'white', )

while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        print(event, values)
        if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, "Exit"):
            break
        
        elif values["-IN-"] == True:
            event, values = window_app1.read()
            if event == "Generate File":
                sg.popup_no_titlebar("You selected the 1st app", background_color="white", button_color=("darkblue"), text_color="black")
        elif values["-IN2-"] == True:
            event, values = window_app2.read()
            if event == "Generate File":
                sg.popup_no_titlebar("You selected the 2nd app", background_color="white", button_color=("darkblue"), text_color="black")

        elif values["-IN3-"] == True:
            event, values = window_app3.read()
            if event == "Generate File":
                sg.popup_no_titlebar("You selected the 3rd app", background_color="white", button_color=("darkblue"), text_color="black")

window.close()
```

How can I make it possible? To repeat an event how many time I want to, without closing and opening  the app all over again?

Comment: You didn't post a [mcve], so I can only make guesses here.  The code you did post seems to expect that all three of the sub-windows already exist; my guess is that something in their individual handling is completely destroying the window when you're finished with it, leaving it in a state where the window cannot be used again.  (And as an aside: if you want the user to choose *exactly one* of the applications, the choices should be radio buttons, rather than checkboxes.)

Comment: Thank you jason, I will edit my post ASAP and provide the whole example.

Comment: Hi Naiara.  @jasonharper is likely correct.  I will also point out that one can prefer using a single window with hidden sections rather than modal pop-up windows.  That is, layout one monster window that has 'panes' and then hide or unhide panes.  The panes are pin controls, like `def as_pin(pane, key): return [ sg.pin(sg.Column(pane, key=key, visible=False))` and use `window[paneName].update(visible=True)` to use the pane.  Maybe this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your tip, Charles! Actually, I already updated a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

There're something wrong.

- window_appx will be shown when method `read` called

  - if close button clicked, then window destroyed, and method `read` will always return `(None, None)`, so you cannot find window any more.
  - if `"Generate File"` clicked, focus still kept at the same window_appx window, but the code back to main window to read, so you will find not working if you click `"Generate File"` again.

Demo code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def sub_window(index):
    layout = [
        [sg.Text(f"This is the sub-window {index}.")],
        [sg.Button('Submit'), sg.Button('Cancel')],
    ]
    win = sg.Window(f'Window {index}', layout)
    event, values = win.read(close=True)
    return event, values

layout = [
    [sg.Radio(key, 'Radio', enable_events=True, key=key) for key in 'ABC'],
    [sg.Button('Submit'), sg.Button('Cancel')],
]
window = sg.Window('Main Window', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Submit' or event in 'ABC':
        for key in 'ABC':
            if values[key]:
                e, v = sub_window(key)

window.close()
```

Comment: It is a great demo, Jason. The problem is the sub_window. In my real case I have to run 3 different functions (If event == "Generate File" --> run function(def 1) for example) . I can not Group in 1 subwindow

Comment: It demo the way how you open a new window, close it before you back to main window. It's not necessary to have same statements in your code. You have the value for which radio element selected, you can judge which function to call by it when in `sub_window`. The same, you don;t have to group them in one subwindow, how to work all depend on your programming.

Answer (score 0):

PySimpleGui can only use a Layout once.  That is why you can't call the window a second time with the same layout variable.

There are 2 main solutions for this limitation:

1. define a generatLayout function that returns a layout

```
def generateLayout():
    layout = []
    layout.append([sg.Text("Sample Text")])
    layout.append([sg.B("Button")])
    return layout

window = sg.Window("Master Window", generatelayout(), background_color='white')
```

2. create a master Layout and then copy that layout to the a new variable using the .copy() function:

```
masterLayout = [[sg.Text("Sample Text")],[sg.B("Button")]]
currentLayout = masterLayout.copy()
window = sg.Window("Master Window",currentLayout, background_color='white')
```